# Why doesnt my listview builder show any items

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I made data models from JSON and created class spaces to provide the data on the spaces. I have tried to implement future builder and then access the data using snapshot,  that works but why doesnt this work. The loading spinner works. print statement inside if statement for listview also works. just no items. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWJ47.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mg2rn.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYN4A.png)

Comment: Can you include minimal code-snippet instead of code-image

Comment: Can you try adding jsonDecode. Example : jsonDecode(response.body)

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Try to [edit] your question and copy-paste them into the question itself in between \`\`\` the code \`\`\`.